# Get Value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get value of span by using class and paragraph id??

Code

```js
 function doit_onkeypress(a) {
     debugger;
     if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13) {
         alert(a);
         var splitdata;
         span_array = [];//define array

         $(".token").each(function () {// iterate over same class spans
             console.log($(this).text()); // print the text of each span
             span_array.push($(this).text());// push span text to array
         });
         console.log(span_array); // you can save data an array for further use
         var final_string = span_array.join(); //join array value as string
         console.log(final_string); // check string 
         splitdata = final_string
         document.getElementById("hdnvaluearray").value = final_string;
         document.getElementById("hdnvaluearray").value = a;
     }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="para" onkeypress="javascript:  doit_onkeypress(this.id);">
    <span class="token">test1</span>
     <span class="token">test2</span>
     <span class="token">test3</span>
</p>

<p id="para2" onkeypress="javascript:  doit_onkeypress(this.id);">
    <span class="token">test4</span>
     <span class="token">test5</span>
     <span class="token">test6</span>
</p>
```

This code show me the span values like test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6
but i want to show these span values
(When click on First paragraph  show output) like  test1,test2,test3
(When click on Second paragraph  show output)like  test4,test5,test6

Comment: what do you actually want? an array or just the text in the p?

Comment: i want array of focus <p> @pete

Comment: Ok so second question - the p is not content editable so how do you expect to capture a keypress event inside it?  Do you mean that you want this event to fire onclick of the p?

Comment: Actually i am using this function For Token Generate so one input tag also included here but i m not showing in this ques and i think this is not necessary

Comment: The easiest way to get the array, but is Jquery is :
$(document).on("click", "#para", function (){var array= $(".token").map(function () {
       return $(this).text()
   }).toArray();});

Comment: How can I trigger the event without input field? [mcve]

Comment: You are using `event`, which is not specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your code:

1. Add the `event`

   ```
   function doit_onkeypress(a, event) {
   ```

   ...

   ```
   <p id="para" tabindex="0" onkeypress="javascript:  doit_onkeypress(this.id, event);">
   ```
2. Add the id into the jQuery selector

   ```
   $("#" + a + ".token").each(function () {
   ```
3. Add a tabindex to paragraph, so that it can be focused.

This is how it works for me:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<p id="para" tabindex="0" onkeypress="doit_onkeypress(this.id, event);">
    <span class="token">test1</span>
    <span class="token">test2</span>
    <span class="token">test3</span>
</p>

<p id="para2" tabindex="1" onkeypress="doit_onkeypress(this.id, event);">
    <span class="token">test4</span>
    <span class="token">test5</span>
    <span class="token">test6</span>
</p>
<script>
function doit_onkeypress(a, event) {
    debugger;
    if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13) {
        alert(a);
        var splitdata;
        span_array = [];//define array

        $(".token").each(function () {// iterate over same class spans
            console.log($(this).text()); // print the text of each span
            span_array.push($(this).text());// push span text to array
        });
        console.log(span_array); // you can save data an array for further use
        var final_string = span_array.join(); //join array value as string
        console.log(final_string); // check string 
        splitdata = final_string
        document.getElementById("hdnvaluearray").value = final_string;
        document.getElementById("hdnvaluearray").value = a;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for Answer  ,its work properly for <p id="para"> but event not generate on click <p id="para2">

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace This .

$(".tknz-token-label")

$("#para .token").each(function () {
});